# Getting to know the field on which query was hit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Using Elasticsearch through Searchkick.

My documents look something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f8672f258f83ac4e7783e5"),
    "n" : "Figth Club",
    "dst" : "video",
    "detail" : {
        est: "El club de la lucha",
        ent: "Figth club",
        hut: "Harcosok klubja"
    }
}
```

My Item model:

```
class Item
 include Mongoid::Document
 searchkick

 def search_data
        {
            n: n,
            est: detail.est,
            ent: detail.ent,
            hut: detail.hut,
        }
 end

end
```

The search query would look something like:

```
Item.search(query, fields: [:n, :est, :ent, :hut], limit: 10).to_a
```

I would like to know what field the query was found on. For example, if `query="El club de la lucha"` I want to know that `detail.est` is the fields where it has been found on. Is that possible?

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to highlight the results that match your search. 
Please take a look at the offered api.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html

Your query should look like this.

```
{
    "query" : {...},
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
             "_all" : {}
        }
    }
}
```